# alingnment of three anchors in html5

Tags: css, html

following code aligns my anchors in different line on specified position. however i feel desire for aligning my tags in the same line on right, center and left position. Can anyone tell me what will be the mistake and what will be the proper code?

```
<div>
<a href="index.html">previous</a>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<a href="courses.html">next</a>
</div>
<div style="margin-left:200px">
<a href="#sobhasaria">top</a>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are wrapping `a` element inside `div`. try with `float`.

Comment: so what will be the right code...i am beginner in html and css field...

Comment: use floats on the divs

Comment: check this http://jsbin.com/vanuqenu/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

`'div'` is Block Level Element. '`a`' is inline element

Here is The Basics:

**Block Level Element:-**     Block Level Element Always Display On `'New Line'`.

**Inline Element:-**
inline element display on `'Same line'`.

So You Are Wrapping inline element with block level element.Thats why Your Anchor displaying on new line.

**UPDATE:-**

You can also change the default behaviour of element. It means you can change how the element displayed as `'Block Or Inline'` by Using the following css property

```
    element{
        display: [block|inline|none]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can align the div using multiple way. Using `float` using `display:table-cell;` you also can use new CSS3 property called `flex`. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vanuqenu/1/edit)**.

```
body{display: flex;} /*set this property for parent div and all child will be aligned I set it for body*/
div{float:left;}
div{display:table-cell;}
div{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: you can use any of these property